# Counting Polygons using Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, maps, artificial-intelligence

**Desired Outcome** I would like to count Polygons from a given image using a Python script. I am looking for a Python library/module or code example that can trained, like an AI, on attached image such that when I provide another similar image it can count the polygons correctly.

Practical use case for this would be to count the number of homes in a given area. See attached image[Map of neighborhood with houses outlined with red polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Owfx.png)

Any suggestions where to start?
I'm new to Stack overflow so if there is any further clarification required on this posted question, please ask (rather than simply marking this question down or disabling it).

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you input the image as `text`, you should use `numpy` or kinda sorts of libs.

If you input as `.jpg/.png/...` , you should try to use `tensorflow` or `numpy` as AI.

Comment: Thank you. The input will be as an image (.jpg or .png).

Comment: My pleasure, and by the way, I suggest learn some knowledge and algorithms about AI. (E.g. tensorflow or pytorch)